# Error on search.run().getRange while loading a saved search in suitescript 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have loaded a saved search in my `beforeLoad` userevent script.
When I try to run the search after applying one filter, Netsuite throws an `UNEXPECTED_ERROR`. Can anyone suggest any reason for this error?

```
  var poRec = context.newRecord;
  var countItem = poRec.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
  var reqValue = poRec.getValue({ fieldId:'custbody_reqfield' });

  var itemSearch = search.load({
    id: 'customsearch_anis_item_search'
  });
  log.error('itemSearch', itemSearch);

  if (!!reqValue) {
    itemSearch.filters.push(
      search.createFilter({
        name: "custitem_an_test_field",
        operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
        values: reqValue
      })
    );
  }

  var results = itemSearch.run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });//ERROR ON THIS LINE(line:181)
```

The Error is as follows:

```
{
  "type":"error.SuiteScriptError",
  "name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
  "message":null,
  "stack": 
    [
      "getRange(N/searchObject)",
      "myAfterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/sample_ue.js:181)",
      "afterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/sample_ue.js:35)"
    ],
  "cause":
    {
      "type":"internal error",
      "code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
      "details":null,
      "userEvent":"aftersubmit",
      "stackTrace":
        [
          "getRange(N/searchObject)",
          "myAfterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/sample_ue.js:181)",
          "afterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/sample_ue.js:35)"
       ],
     "notifyOff":false
    },
    "id":"f414b115-c840-40de-8cf8-c0148da0c506-2d323032302e30322e3035",
    "notifyOff":false,
    "userFacing":false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the search.filters array or use a filter expression.

```
var newFilters = [];
newFilters.push(
      search.createFilter({
        name: "custitem_an_test_field",
        operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
        values: reqValue
      }));
itemSearch.filters = newFilters;      

// OR

itemSearch.filters = ["custitem_an_test_field", "ANYOF", reqValue];
```

Comment: This will overwrite any existing filters on the saved search.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh true. The OP would need to copy the filters to the new array and then apply it otherwise.